# Sum values of one column depending on the ID of another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with many values as such (this is an oversimplified example):

| IDx | Namex | Pricex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 5 |
| 2 | b | 2 |
| 1 | a2 | 5 |
| 3 | c | 3 |
| 2 | b2 | 9 |

and another table with only the ID, in which I'd like to add a column that shows the addition of all the values that match that ID, in this example:

| IDy | Totaly |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 3 |

I'm guessing this is a combination of vlookup with sum or sumif, I've tried so far:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(IDy1,$IDx$1:$IDx$5,$Pricex$1:$Pricex$5),// don't know how to proceed here
```

Comment: You can take a look at `SUMIF` formula and post back if you have difficulties implementing it.

Comment: or just use a pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

B5:B9 = IDx

B16,D5 = Price

```
=SUMIF(B$5:B$9,B16,D$5:D$9)
```

[image]

Comment: Check your fill-down and/or use of $. The SUMIF ranges in E17 and E18 have slid down from where they're supposed to be (B$5:B$9 and D$5:D$9)